# Cambiar DATEADD cuando es día Lunes - TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql, transacciones

Resulta que tengo una query que lo que hace es traerme indicadores de una fecha especificada como variable. Esa variable es:

```
DECLARE @fecha DATE = CAST(GETDATE() as date)
```

Sin embargo, ahora necesito obtener indicadores de **esa fecha y dos días atrás**. El problema que tengo es que si cae día lunes, me traerá indicadores del día sábado y si cae día martes me traerá del día domingo.

Yo lo estaba haciendo de esta forma:

```
WHERE cast(po.CreatedDate as date) BETWEEN @fecha and DATEADD(d,-2,@fecha)
```

Pero lo que necesito es definir la forma de hacer el `WHERE` con dos días hábiles hacia atrás. Si `@fecha` es día lunes o martes, me traiga lo del día Viernes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la instrucción DATEPART para saber si es lunes o martes, ya que te dará el resultado 1 o 2. Puedes adapatar la siguiente query para tu ejemplo:

```
where cast(po.CreatedDate as date) BETWEEN GETDATE() AND
CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) <= 2 THEN 
    DATEADD(d,-2 - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()), GETDATE())
ELSE 
    DATEADD(d,-2, GETDATE() )
END;
```

Tendrás que reemplazar el GETDATE por tu fecha. Lo que hace esta query es que si es lunes o martes, le resta -2 (para pasar a sabado o domingo) - (1 o 2) dependiendo de si es lunes o martes, de esta manera si es martes te cogerá hasta el viernes y si es lunes te cogerá hasta el jueves.